# Can JavaFX TableView be partly editable?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, tableview

I've got a JavaFX TableView which possesses two columns. This tables uses a ObservableList `gasRatioMeasures` as its model.

```
public class GasRatioMeasureBean {
    private String number;
    private String measure;
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = "Measure" + (number + 1) + "(%)";
    }
    public String getMeasure() {
        return measure;
    }
    public void setMeasure(String measure) {
        this.measure = measure;
    }
}
```

I'd like to set one of them editable and the other non-editable.

Firstly I tried the FXML way:

```
<TableView layoutX="24.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="215.0" fx:id="measureTableView">
    <columns>
         <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="100.0" sortable="false" text="No" fx:id="measureNumbersColumn" />
         <TableColumn editable="true" prefWidth="110.0" sortable="false" text="Measures" fx:id="measuresColumn" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

But this didn't work. The table is always not editable.

I also tried out the java way:

```
private void initMeasuresTableView() {
    measureNumbersColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GasRatioMeasureBean, String>("number"));
    measureNumbersColumn.setEditable(false);
    measuresColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GasRatioMeasureBean, String>("measure"));
    measuresColumn.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<GasRatioMeasureBean, String>>() {
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<GasRatioMeasureBean, String> measure) {
                ((GasRatioMeasureBean) measure.getTableView().getItems().get(
                measure.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setMeasure(measure.getNewValue());
            }
        }
    );

    measureTableView.setItems(gasRatioMeasures);
    measureTableView.setEditable(true);
}
```

But this didn't work either. All the table kept uneditable.

If TableColumn has an `editable` property, then it should be able to be set separately.

Please help me if you know where I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

PS: the column measureNumbersColumn can already been displayed normally (when I haven't initialized measuresColumn).

PPS: I also tried instead of `setOnEditCommit` `setOnEditStart` .  `setOnEditCommit` is not called, but `setOnEditStart` can be called just in editable column.

Comment: See [Oracle's TableView tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) for the part "Editing Data in the Table" where the partial editing has been implemented.

Answer (score 7):

You did not use a cell factory that supports editing. You need to do:

```
measureNumbersColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn())
```

This will make your column use a `TextFieldTableCell` instead of the default `TableCell`. 
TextFieldTableCell supports editing (look at the source code and look for `startEdit` method).

Alternatively if you are not happy with the behavior of the TextFieldTableCell, you can write your own implementation of TableCell, and override the startEdit, cancelEdit, and updateItem methods.

```
measureNumbersColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<GasRatioMeasureBean,String>, TableCell<GasRatioMeasureBean,String>>() {

    @Override
    public TableCell<GasRatioMeasureBean, String> call(
            TableColumn<GasRatioMeasureBean, String> arg0) {
        return MyOwnTableCell(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the way by which you can make editable columns in TableView.

tblViewPerson.setEditable(true);

```
        // Making editable columns 
        // For ID

        tblColID.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

        tblColID.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setId(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Is the `setID` the method of POJO class?

Comment: Method for controller class for making table column editable.